# Reading in radio button selections in JS

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get a popup window to display whatever was entered into the form. I have managed to get it display the Name that was entered into the form, but would also like it to display the rating given in the website (radio buttons) using only JavaScript and HTML.

```
<form>
<fieldset>
<legend><b>Details</b></legend>

<label>First Name </label><input id = "fname" type="text" autofocus="" placeholder="Enter first name" name = "fname"><br><br>
<label>Last Name </label><input type="text" placeholder="Enter last name"><br><br>
<label>Email </label><input type="email" placeholder="Enter valid email">  <button onclick="myFunction()">Help</button><br><br>

</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<legend><b>Rating</b></legend>

<label>Website Rating:</label>
 <input type="radio" name="Rating" value="1">* &#40;1 Star&#41;
 <input type="radio" name="Rating" value="2">* * &#40;2 Star&#41;
 <input type="radio" name="Rating" value="3">* * * &#40;3 Star&#41;
 <input type="radio" name="Rating" value="4">* * * * &#40;4 Star&#41;
 <input type="radio" name="Rating" value="5">* * * * * &#40;5 Star&#41;<br>

</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<legend><b>Comments</b></legend>

<label>Comments on the website:</label>
<textarea name="feedback1" rows="8" cols="70"></textarea><br>

</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<legend><b>Updates</b></legend>
Do you want to receive updates via Email?<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="updateYes" value="Yes">Yes 
<input type="checkbox" name="update" value="No" checked>No<br>
</fieldset>

<input type="reset" value="Reset">
<button onclick="myFunction2()" type = "submit">Submit</button>

</form>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    alert("Please enter a valid Email adress into the 'Email' field");
}

function myFunction2() {
    alert("Thank you for your feedback " + document.getElementById('fname').value + ", You have rated the website ");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use querySelector for this:

```
var value = document.querySelector('input[name=Rating]:checked').value;
alert("Thank you for your feedback " + value + ", You have rated the website ");
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/bvaughn/kaqqsrc1/

You could also use getElementsByName:

```
var value;
var radios = document.getElementsByName("Rating");
for(var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
    if(radios[i].checked) value = radios[i].value;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/bvaughn/1qqqtafu/

Answer (score 0):

Get the selected radiobutton by looping over them:

```
function myFunction2() {

  var checkedRadioButton, inputs, rating;

  inputs = document.getElementsByName("Rating");
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if (inputs[i].checked) {
        checkedRadioButton = inputs[i];
        break;
    }
  }   

  if (checkedRadioButton) {
      rating = checkedRadioButton.value;
  }

  alert("Thank you for your feedback " + document.getElementById('fname').value + ", You have rated the website " + rating);
```

}

https://jsfiddle.net/d5jo235p/